# Como fazer o visual studio 2015 publicar apenas os arquivos que são mais atuais?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, deploy

Coloquei um projeto no visual studio 2015 para experimentar a ferramenta.

É uma aplicação asp.net mvc, faço a publicação dela direto no servidor por FTP.

Botão direito no projeto, publish, aí criei um profile FTP e falei para não excluir os arquivos antes de publicar.

No visual studio 2013 isso é o suficiente para ele não publicar tudo toda vez, no 2015 ele está publicando tudo, não deleta os arquivos como solicitado, mas sobre escreve todos eles.

Alguém sabe como fazer isso não acontecer?

Comment: Acho que não existe este comportamento que você quer por publicação normal. Só por Web Deploy o Visual Studio faz isso, mas de repente pode ser que eu precise pesquisar um pouco mais.

Comment: O que não entendo é pq o visual studio 2013 faz isso, um exemplo que consigo ver claramente é a dll log4net, ela fica dentro do bin, quando mando publicar pelo 2013 ele não a substitui, quando eu mando pelo 2015 ele substitui ela e todas as outras, já conferi a configuração do profile de ftp e os dois estão idênticos, isso que não entendo.

Comment: Não usei o VS2015 tempo suficiente pra te dar uma resposta, mas acredito que este comportamento ocorra pela segurança do *Build*. Antigamente era comum ocorrer erros muito esquisitos por esse comportamento de evitar a escrita, principalmente em DLL's de bancos de dados.

Answer (score 1):

Essa funcionalidade que existia no VS2012 para publicação parcial por FTP não existe mais, foi removida. Acho que só no Web Deploy ainda é possível fazer a publicação parcial de acordo com modificações.

Outra forma, seria você fazer o upload por fora do VS (totalmente externo, ou até mesmo configurado em um "build step" de uma configuração de build específica, por exemplo a RELEASE ou criar uma configuração exclusiva para publicação)
Ai neste caso você teria que criar os scripts (pode até ser um outro projeto do VS, uma DLL que faz o trabalho sujo, pode ser um PowerShell, Node.JS, etc) para fazer a validação do que foi alterado e para fazer o upload.

Segue um exemplo usando GULP (Node.js) para monitorar as alterações: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39795922/1890220

Neste exemplo ele monitora os arquivos em tempo real e a cada modificação salva, ele efetua o envio (upload) do arquivo (pode ser catastrófico em ambiente de produção, já que você pode mudar algo para testar e ele fazer o upload em produção e parar sua aplicação toda, se não for bem configurado. Entenda bem configurado como selecionando apenas extensões/tipos de arquivos que não apresentam riscos a saúde da aplicação)